# MLFlow recipe for multi-label classification

Tags: multilabel-classification, mlflow

How can I setup a MLFlow recipe for multi-label classification?  The [documentation](https://github.com/mlflow/recipes-classification-template#problem-statement) specifies that the `target_col` must be of cardinality two (i.e., no multi-class or multi-label classification).